how can I disable colored output when hitting ruby warnings and errors?
ruby 2.7.2 on linux
I run ruby in a way that creates error messages.  Part of the messages come out white which, on the very light xterm background I'm using, is unintelligable.  Example...
% /usr/bin/env ruby design_parser.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from design_parser.rb:175:in `<main>'
design_parser.rb:175:in 
`read': No such file or directory ... blah...blah... (Errno::ENOENT) 

The "Traceback" and the last line are white, I can't read them, have to cp/paste them somewhere to see what they are saying.  Very annoying.
Looked for but did not find anything from 'ruby -h' to shut the coloring off.
Can this be done ?

I don't understand.  Doesn't look like something that could be done from the linux prompt.

At first you say you want to disable colored output but then you say the offending lines are white. So you want to make the white lines colored?

It's not about output from the ruby script, it's about output from whatever reports stuff like syntax errors in the ruby script, stuff that gets checked before execution/interpretation.  It's outputting colored text that I can't read, basically because I prefer to work with a light colored background in xterm.

So the issue does not appear to be color but rather "highlighting" which is ANSI bold (actually just increases the brightness of the current color) eg.
"\e[1m#{text}\e[0m"

Ruby 2.7
As mentioned in the docs for Exception#full_message

If highlight is true the default error handler will send the messages to a tty...
The default values of these options depend on $stderr and its tty? at the timing of a call.

The problem is in 2.7.2 it does not appear that underlying exceptions flow through this method when sending exceptions to the output, so the simplest solution I have come to for 2.7 (alternatives welcome) is to mask that the $stderr is a terminal by using a Delegator and defining tty? as false.
require 'delegate'
class FalseTerminal < SimpleDelegator 
    def tty? 
      false
    end 
end 
$stderr = FalseTerminal.new($stderr)

You could apply the same concept to $stdout if necessary.
Ruby 3
The 2.7 solution is equally applicable but masking $stderr seems awkward given the alternative.
In ruby 3 there is the addition of the Exception#detailed_message method which the terminal output does flow through and the error_highlight feature also implements its own.
Since error_highlight is enabled by default we can simply change the highlight option for these calls as follows:
module NoHighlight
  def detailed_message(**args) 
    super(**args.merge(highlight: false)) 
  end 
end
ErrorHighlight::CoreExt.prepend(NoHighlight)

Then execute the code as ruby design_parser.rb
If you also need this to work without error_highlight you just need to include this in the Exception class as well
Exception.prepend(NoHighlight) 

So the full code to disable everywhere could be
module NoHighlight 
  def detailed_message(**args)
    super(**args.merge(highlight: false))
  end
end

Exception.prepend(NoHighlight)
ErrorHighlight::CoreExt.prepend(NoHighlight) if defined?(ErrorHighlight)


Seems complicated to have to go into the code to suppress the eye candy stuff for stuff like identifying syntax errors in the ruby code.  Defaulting to colored/highlighted output by default is fine, as long as you provide a way to shut that off as a cmd line option.  And if they want to insist on colors, at least be sensitive to what the user's background color is so that the output is readable.
I suppose I can just redirect to a flat file, cat it and ignore all the escaped special chars.

@daveg if you redirect to a flat file then tty? will be false anyway so there will be no syntax highlighting. I have no idea what your current output looks like maybe a screenshot (not generally recommended) would add to the current context. Either way this is the only solutions I have found at this point. This type of highlighting is baked right in to the c code for ruby.

@daveg an alternate approach could be to just change the colors in xterm for instance: https://superuser.com/questions/650396/set-xterm-text-color
